# Functional programming in Python

Tags: python, functional-programming

**Functional programming** is one of the programming paradigms in Python. It treats computation as the **evaluation of mathematical functions** and avoids **state** and **mutable data**. I am trying to understand how Python incorporates functional programming.

Consider the following factorial program (`factorial.py`):

```
def factorial(n, total):
    if n == 0:
        return total
    else:
        return factorial(n-1, total*n)

num = raw_input("Enter a natural number: ")
print factorial(int(num), 1)
```

That code avoids mutable data, because we are not changing the value of any variable. We are only recursively calling the factorial function with a new value.

- If the example given above for functional programming is correct, then what does avoiding state mean?
- Does functional programming only mean that I must use only functions whenever I have computations (as given in the above example)?
- If the given example is wrong, what is a simple example with an explanation?

Comment: Avoiding *mutable* state: a program without any state is worthless. In any case, see [Functional Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) - while Python does support first-class/higher-order-functions, and recursion etc, it is hardly a FP language.

Comment: Technically speaking "n-1" and "total*n" are evaluated before the new recursive-call to factorial is made.

Comment: Avoiding state means you always get the same output from a function called with the same arguments.

Comment: @stark can you give an examle where the function is called with the same arguments but the output is different.

Comment: @GuruSwaroop `input('Name:')` or `random.random()`.

Comment: For python, increment and return a class variable.

Answer (score 4):

The example is correct for functional programming. *And* a good example of what **not** to do in Python because it is inefficient and doesn't scale.  Python doesn't have any tail-call optimisation, so recursive calls should not be used solely to avoid imperative loops.  If you really start programming in this style in Python, your programs will end with runtime errors eventually.

You are describing *pure functional programming* which is not something Python could be used for.

Python supports functional programming to some degree in the sense that functions are first class values. That means functions can be passed to other functions and returned as results from functions. And the standard library contains functions also found in most functional programming languages standard libraries, like `map()`, `filter()`, `reduce()`, and the stuff in the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) modules.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing from http://ua.pycon.org/static/talks/kachayev/#/8 where he makes a comparison between the way one thinks of imperative and functional programs. The example is borrowed.

Imperative:

```
expr, res = "28+32+++32++39", 0
for t in expr.split("+"):
    if t != "":
        res += int(t)

print res
```

Functional:

```
from operator import add
expr = "28+32+++32++39"
print reduce(add, map(int, filter(bool, expr.split("+"))))
```

Comment: I don't really see what point you are trying to make here unless perhaps it is that imperative is easier to understand and fp is less readable. While that is true here I doubt it is always the case. If you wanted readable then I would contend that `print(sum(int(n) for n in expr.split("+") if n))` would be clearest but that's really neither functional nor imperative. That is where Python's strength lies: mixing paradigms rather than being a slave to one.

Comment: @Duncan What's not functional in that line? Apart from the side effect of `print()` there's just calls of pure functions and expressions. It translates almost 1:1 to Haskell: `putStrLn $ show $ sum [read n::Int | n <- splitOn "+" expr, n /= ""]`. `splitOn` is imported from `Data.List.Split` from the `split` package.

Comment: The link is broken (404).

Answer (score 0):

> If the given example is wrong, then kindly provide another simple example with an explanation.

It’s not, and it shows a realistic problem to start with, which you’ll see if you call `factorial` with a huge number. The maximum recursion depth will be reached. Python doesn’t have tail call optimization.

> It the example given above for functional programming is correct, then what does avoiding state mean.

It means (in Python) that once a variable had been assigned, you *should* not reassign a new value, or change the value that you assigned to that variable.

> Secondly, does functional programming only mean that, I must use only functions whenever I have computations (as given in the above example)

Functional programming is quite broad. Python is a multi-paradigm language that supports some functional programming concepts.

Functional programming means that all computations should be seen as mathematical functions.

I wrote a post about it that explains all the above in greater detail: *[Use Functional Programming In Python](https://menziess.github.io/howto/use/functional-programming-in-python/)*

Answer (score -1):

##### Basics

Functional programming is a paradigm where we use only expressions and no statements. Statements do something like an if, whereas expressions evaluate mathematical stuff. We try to avoid mutability (values getting changed), since we only want pure functions. Pure functions don't have side effects, meaning that a function, given the same input, always produces the same output. We want functions to be pure, since they are easier to debug. By doing this, we are describing what a function is, as opposed to giving steps about how to do something and we write a lot less code. Functional programming is often called declarative, while other approaches are called imperative.

##### Utilities

Know about built-in functions, since they are so useful. For starters: *abs*, *round*, *pow*, *max* & *min*, *sum*, *len*, *sorted*, *reversed*, *zip*, and *range*.

##### Lambdas

Anonymous functions or lambdas are pure functions that take input and produce a value. There isn't any return statement, since we are returning what we are evaluating. You can also give them a name by just declaring a variable.

```py
(lambda x, y: x + y)(1, 1)
```

```py
add = lambda x, y: x + y
add(1, 1)
```

##### Ternary operator

Since we are working with expressions, instead of using *if* statements for logic, we use the ternary operator.

```py
(expression) if (condition) else (expression2)
```

##### Map, filter & reduce

We also need a way of looping. This comes with list comprehension.
In this example we add one to each array element.

```py
inc = lambda x: [i + 1 for i in x]
```

We can also operate on elements that meet a condition.

```py
evens = lambda x: [i for i in x if (i % 2) == 0]
```

Some people say that that is the correct Pythonic way of doing things. But people who are more serious use a different approach: *map*, *filter*, and *reduce*. These are the building blocks of functional programming. While *map* and *filter* are built-in functions, *reduce* used to be, but now is in the [functools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) module. To use it, import it:

```py
from functools import reduce
```

*Map* is a function that takes a function and calls it on the elements of an array. The result of a map function is unfortunately unreadable, so you need to turn it into a tuple or a collection.

```py
inc = lambda x: tuple(map(lambda y: y + 1, x))
```

*Filter* is a function that calls a function on an array, keeps the elements that output True and removes the ones that are False. Like *map*, it's not readable.

```py
evens = lambda x: tuple(filter(lambda y: (y % 2) == 0, x))
```

*Reduce* takes a function that has two parameters. One is the result of the last time it was called & one is the new value. It keeps doing this until it reduces down to a value.

```py
from functools import reduce
m_sum = lambda x: reduce(lambda y, z: y + z, x)
```

##### *Let* and *do*

A lot of functional programming languages have *do*. *Do* is a function that takes n arguments, evaluates all of them and returns the value of the last one. Python doesn't have do, but I created one myself.

```py
do = lambda *args: tuple(map(lambda y: y, args))[-1]
```

Here's an example using do that prints something and exits.

```py
print_err = lambda x: do(print(x), exit())
```

We use *do* to get imperative advantages.

*Let* allows some expression to be equal to something in a expression. In Python, most people do that as follows.

```py
def something(x):
  y = x + 10
  return y * 3
```

Python 3.8 adds the expression assignment operators :=. So that code can now be written as a lambda.

```py
something = lambda x: do(y := x + 10, y * 3)
```

##### Working with impure systems

The console, the file system, the web, etc. are immutable and impure and we need a way to work with them. In some languages like [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) you have [monads](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)), which are wrappers for functions. [Clojure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clojure) allows the use of impure functions. In Python, a multi-paradigm language, we don't need anything, since it's not just functional. Print is an impure function.

##### Recursion

Your example uses recursion. Recursion uses the call stack, which is a small chunk of memory that is used for calling functions. It can get full and crash. A lot of functional programming languages use something known as [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) to help with the problem of recursion, but Python doesn't have it. So avoid recursion as much as possible.

##### Answers

1. Avoiding state is being immutable, meaning not changing the value of something.
2. In functional programming, everything is an expression, which is a function. We don't have that in Python though, since it's multi-paradigm.
3. In a more functional way, your code would be written as follows. Also it's not functional due to using an if statement instead of a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

```py
from functools import reduce
factorial = lambda x: reduce(lambda y, z: y*z, range(1,x+1))
```

This produces a range of 1 to x and multiplies all the values using range.